# Session settings - timeout

Tags: security, session

I set the session expiration timeout for my org to 8 hours in sandbox.
However, the session continues expiring at 15 minutes.

Can anyone let me know, whether I need to change another setting.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have IT-based browser limits or resets?  Even when SFDC is set to a specific time, if your internal policies reset connections, you'll be bumped.  Also, 8-hours?

Comment: Individual profiles also have Session Timeout setting. Did you check that?

Comment: @SantanuHalder thank you so much. So,  what is the order of priority. The settings on Profile level will be considered above the general session settings.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right!

Comment: @SantanuHalder If I set session timeout on Profile to be 8 hours and on general settings to be 15 minutes, then?

Answer (score 1):

> The settings for session duration and password policies at the profile level override the settings at the organization level.
>
> Until you set the Session Timeout on a profile, the organization-wide Timeout value in the Session Settings applies to users of the profile. Once set, the Session Timeout on a profile overrides the organization-wide Timeout value for users of that profile. Changes to the organization-wide Timeout value will not apply to users of a profile with its own Session Timeout value.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_profile_additions.htm

---

### Org wide:

[image]

---

### Profile specific:

[image: enter link description here]